# About private member of Class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, private

I have a question about private member of Class in C++:

I have a class defined like this:

```
class Hello
{
   private:
      int a[2][2] = {{1,1},{2,2}};
   public:
      int* getA();
} hello;
```

`a` is a array, which is private member of class hello, which is protected from accessing from outside of the class, but if I use `getA()` to return the address of array a like this:

```
int* Hello::getA()
{
   return &a[2][2];
}
```

and outside of the class `hello` uses a variable to keep the address of `a[2][2]` like this:

```
int* i = getA();
```

does `i` have the address of `a[2][2]`? can we modify the `array` outside of class like this? **Is the `a[2][2]` still protected by `private` keyword?**

Comment: `&a[2][2];` is returning a pointer to outside the array's range.

Comment: You can do it, but you shouldn't.

Comment: what you mean? if I do not want to modify the value, just want to read the value of array, are there better ways to do it?

Comment: Why did you post this question, and not wait for [your other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688068/how-to-operate-two-dimensional-array-using-functions-in-c) to get answered?

Comment: I think they are two different question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What happens is that you've returned a pointer into a private member. Once the caller has that pointer, they can freely modify the pointed-to array element. There is no protection, and `private` is no longer relevant.

Furthermore, you have no control over what the caller does with that pointer, or how long they hold on to it. If there are some `a` invariants you need to enforce, you can't. If `a` is dynamically allocated and you need to reallocate it, you can't.

This is a good demonstration of why leaking pointers into private members is often not a great idea.

(Here, I assume you meant to return a pointer to a valid element; `a[2][2]` is out of bounds.)

> if I do not want to modify the value, just want to read the value of array, are there better ways to do it?

In such a case, either return the element by value or by `const` reference (you could also return it by `const` pointer, but that would make it unnecessarily awkward for the caller).

Comment: I think he wanted to return a pointer _to the array_, not to an element.

Comment: @MooingDuck: If that's the OP's intention, then it's even worse (since it not only leaks pointers, but also exposes the internal layout).

Comment: return the element by value? how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What happens is you run into **undefined behavior**, because `&a[2][2]` accesses invalid indexes.

Other than that, `private` is mostly a keyword for programmers - it enforces no run-time checks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you must return a double pointer for 2-dimensional arrays.

```
int ** Hello::getA()
{
    &a[0][0];
}
```

you can freely do

```
 myHello.getA()[1][1] = value; //better use pointer just in place than storing it anywhere anyway.
```

by the way, arrays are 0 based index, so if you declare

```
int a[5];
```

the maximum addressable index is a[4]
(you have 5 memory locations starting at 0 not at 1.. so you have a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]).

Anyway returning raw pointers is not very good practice until you know what are you doing.

Note also that returnin

```
return &a[1];// is wrong (if you have a[2])
```

because if you do

```
Hello.getA()[1];
```

in reality you are trying to access a[2], and a[2] is not valid since you have up to a[1]
(a[1] is the second value, again a[1] means the second value respect to second value wich is the third value!)

.. if you are lucky that will just give you a segmentation fault. If you are not lucky you will have to search and debug why you get at some point undefined values.